# Программа не печатает

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется программа:

```
import random
def get_forenames_and_surnames():
    forenames = []
    surenames = []
    for names, filename in ((forenames, "data/forenames.txt"),
                            (surenames, "data/surnames.txt")):
        for name in open(filename, encoding="utf8"):
            names.append(name.rstrip())
    return forenames, surenames

forenames, surenames = get_forenames_and_surenames()
fh = open("test-names1.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")
for i in range(100):
    line = "{0} {1}\n".format(random.choice(forenames),
                              random.choice(surnames))
    fh.write(line)
```

[image: Здесь изображены файлы, используемые в программе.]

Однако программа всё равно не печатает имена. Требуемый файл остаётся пустым? Хотя ошибок программа не видит.

Comment: fh.close() в конце

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не закрываете файл(соответственно не сохряняете изменения)

```
fh.close()
```